# Note taking/list making app with dashboard view

Tags: android, web-apps, project-management, note-taking

I've been looking around but I haven't been able to find a note taking app that does quite what I want.
I've been using Google Keep like this:

[image: My current workflow]

I need the app to support:

- Android + web version
- grid style dashboard, like Google Keep
- easy import/export from some semi-standard format (I don't want to get locked in)
- tagging/colors is a plus

Can be free or paid, I don't care.

Google Keep almost fits these requirements, except for the import feature.

Comment: It may be a bit overkill, but look at Trello

Comment: Trello is great, but it doesn't have a dashboard grid view where I can have a look at all my tasks... at least I haven't found one

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [Hitask](https://hitask.com/)?

It supports the following:

- Android + iOS + Web
- All-in-one (calendar + tasks + people) dashboard
- Import / export
- Tagging / coloring

It is free for up to 5 users.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Asana](https://www.asana.com/)? It has board view, calendar view, and list view with tasks/sub-tasks.